# SSH into server but can't SSH out

Tags: centos, ssh

I have two CentOS servers (Version 6.9 and 7.3). No firewalls are running but i cant SSH from CentOS 7.3 server to CentOS 6.9.

So these connections work:

ME -> Both Servers

CentOS 6.9 -> CentOS 7.3

BUT CentOS 7.3 server to any SSH out doesnt work, always gets connection refused.

What could be causing this strange issue?

EDIT:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ******* [**********] port 2020.
debug1: connect to address ************* port 2020: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ********** port 2020: Connection refused
```

Comment: Firewalls, probably. You say none are running, but there being *none anywhere* seems fairly unlikely.

Comment: nothing is running on either server iptables and firewalld are stopped. @ceejayoz

Comment: You have no firewalls in your network infrastructure?

Comment: We have one firewall that can block incoming connections but both IP's are whitelisted.

Comment: Also @ceejayoz i can FTP from CentOS 7.3 to 6.9 and access websites via port 80. It is literally just SSH that doesnt work.

Comment: `connection refused` is uncommon for a firewall issue. Is the SSHd running? Is it running on the default port? Is you computer in hosts.allow, or the other server in hosts.deny? Does the hostname resolve to the correct IP address?

Comment: Both are whitelisted for all connections on both servers and SSHd is running as i can SSH to both servers. but COS 7.3 cant to 6.9

Comment: Could you provide more information about network? Both servers in same network?

Comment: Yeah they are both in the same DataCenter.

Comment: Can you ssh to other servers from the 7.3 server?

Comment: No ssh out of that server works, its all connection refused.

Comment: Please run a connection attempt with `ssh -vvv` from that server and edit the result in your question.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider see edit

Comment: Is it intentional that it connects to port 2020 instead of the default port 22?

Comment: Yeah its a whm installation so the port is changed.

Comment: If _no_ ssh out of that server works, then that server is the one with the problem. Check all the logs on that server. Is selinux enabled on it?

Comment: SELinux is disabled and what logs should i check?

Comment: Can the 2 machines ping each other? What kind of SSH policy did you set up? Password or SSH key? Is the SSH setting the same on both computers?

Comment: You clearly need debug logs from the sshd to which you are trying to connect.  If it' indeed is that which is refusing the connection, the logs will state as much.  If not, then something in between is interfering.

Comment: SSH is via password. they can not ping each other (100% packet loss) BUT i can access them from each other via HTTP and HTTPS and FTP @bert